# Are there galaxies with satellites in retrograde orbit?

Tags: galaxy-rotation-curve

If frame dragging is important for properly calculating galactic rotation curves, it seems that galactic satellites in retrograde orbit should behave as if they experience a different amount of gravitational attraction than those in prograde orbits. My question is: are there known galaxies with satellite objects (satellite galaxies, stellar clusters, etc.) that might provide data to support or refute the importance of including frame dragging in calculating galactic rotation curves?

Comment: can you give a link for "If frame dragging is important for properly calculating galactic rotation curves,".

Comment: found this  https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2021/03/210304145458.htm

Comment: @anna v, https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-021-08967-3.

Comment: thanks, it is the same publication refered in my link. It is the "frame" that I coul not find, the "dragging is there" :).  You are trying to see whether the "Although the relativistic effects are weak " in the conclusions would become "strong" in retrograde motion?

Comment: I dont have a clear intuition of how "frame dragging" works in GR, but if it is comparable to the Lorentz force, it should effectively exert a force in opposite directions for masses moving in prograde and retrograde directions relative to gravitational rotation.  It seems that retrograde masses in circular orbits should move more slowly than those in prograde circular orbits at the same galactic radius.

Comment: found this : https://www.nature.com/articles/431918a . Intriguing  possibility. It needs somebody calculating with GR to be able to answer your question.

Comment: here is a paper with calculations https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.07440

Comment: pointed from here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/can-rotational-frame-dragging-instead-of-dark-matter-explain-the-rotation-speed-of-galaxies.992260/

Comment: It just seems that prograde-vs-retrograde data should be able to settle the question.  Most of the arguments for and against the importance of frame dragging in galactic rotation curves seem to be more opinions and hand waving than hard,  reliable, calculations.

Comment: Globular clusters orbit galaxies in all kinds of spherical orbits, so they should be able to shed some light on this.